# SOQL order by distance internal server error

Tags: apex, soql, query, gack

I am trying to add an `ORDER BY` statement in a SOQL query. I am already using the same statement in the `WHERE` clause of the query, but am getting an error saving it.

> An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 973471439-38882 (132416824)

I'm not sure if this is a platform problem or syntax problem. I am thinking it's a platform problem [based on this post](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=the-address-field-are-no-longer-allowed-in-order-by-clause-in-soql-query-after-spring-18&Id=a1p3A0000018BPm) as I am working out of a Spring 18 sandbox. Oddly, I am able to run the query in that post though.

Query

```
SELECT Id, StartDate, EndDate, Start_Date_Time__c, End_Date_Time__c, Location__r.BillingStreet, Location__r.BillingCity, Maximum_Participants__c,
    Location__r.BillingState, Location__r.BillingPostalCode, Location__r.Name,
    (
        SELECT Id
        FROM CampaignMembers
        WHERE Status != 'Cancelled'
    )
FROM Campaign
WHERE StartDate >= :req.startDate.date()
    AND EndDate <= :req.endDate.date()
    AND DISTANCE(Location__r.BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:req.lat, :req.lng), 'mi') < :req.miles
    AND RecordType.DeveloperName = :SEMINAR_RECORD_TYPE
    AND Available__c = true
    AND StartDate >= :Date.today()
ORDER BY StartDate ASC, DISTANCE(Location__r.BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:req.lat, :req.lng), 'mi') ASC
```

The lat and long values are coming from the method parameters in a model object.

Model:

```
public class SearchModel {
    public String campaignId;
    public Integer miles;
    public String zip;
    public DateTime startDate;
    public DateTime endDate;
    public Decimal lat;
    public Decimal lng;
    public String consultationOrSeminar;
    public String productInterest;
}
```

Comment: It is possible using using Dynamic SOQL, see below

Comment: @Robs yes, this is already an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close the loop here, this behavior (not being able to bind variables in an `ORDER BY` clause) is documented in the `Apex Developer Guide`, though I didn't think to look there earlier. Emphasis mine:

> ## [Using Apex Variables in SOQL and SOSL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm)
>
> SOQL and SOSL statements in Apex can reference Apex code variables and expressions if they’re preceded by a colon (:). This use of a local code variable within a SOQL or SOSL statement is called a bind. The Apex parser first evaluates the local variable in code context before executing the SOQL or SOSL statement. Bind expressions can be used as:
>
> - The search string in FIND clauses.
> - The filter literals in WHERE clauses.
> - The value of the IN or NOT IN operator in WHERE clauses, allowing filtering on a dynamic set of values. Note that this is of particular use with a list of IDs or Strings, though it works with lists of any type.
> - The division names in WITH DIVISION clauses.
> - The numeric value in LIMIT clauses.
> - The numeric value in OFFSET clauses.
>
> **Bind expressions can't be used with other clauses, such as INCLUDES.**

Comment: It is possible using using Dynamic SOQL, see below

Answer (score 2):

Received a response from Salesforce:

> Good Morning !
>
> I have received an update from my tier -3 stating that "Binding variables are NOT allowed in ORDER BY clause, hence adding the following piece of code in an apex thrown Internal Server Error " 
>   DISTANCE(Location__r.BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(:req.lat, :req.lng), 'mi') ASC.
>
> However, adding something like the following works: 
>   ORDER BY StartDate ASC, DISTANCE(Location__r.BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION(43.075861, -87.882772), 'mi') ASC
>
> There is already an idea about this: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l56WAAQ
>
> Please let me know in case of any queries.

Work around:

Convert the soql to a dynamic soql string and execute using `Database.query();`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps write a string query:

```
string processQuery = 'Select  User.FirstName, User.LastName, 
ProfileSkill.Name, EFX_Skill_assessment__c 
FROM ProfileSkillUser WHERE ProfileSkill.Name LIKE \'%' + skill+ '%\'';

DataBase.query(processQuery);
```

And put your lat and long values into the string before execution.

This approach is mentioned here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BHdKIAW

And here

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008ybqIAA

Comment: Read more about Dynamic SOQL here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm

Comment: Also my questions: single quote by curly braces in String.format in Dynamic SOQL might help when implementing it: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211040/using-single-quote-by-curly-braces-in-string-format-in-dynamic-soql

Comment: This is already an answer.