# Using single quote by curly braces in String.format in Dynamic SOQL

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql, string

I'm struggling to use String.format to replace a token with a value when the token is within single quotes:

Example:

```
String query = String.format('SELECT Id FROM Availability WHERE Person__c = \'{0}\'', personId);
```

String query is equal to:

```
SELECT Id FROM Availability WHERE Person__c = {0}
```

Rather than:

```
SELECT Id FROM Availability WHERE Person__c = '234567890'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting the merge field makes it literal text. In order to get the merge field to work, you have to quote the quotes:

```
String query = String.format('SELECT Id FROM Availability WHERE Person__c = \'\'{0}\'\'', personId);
```

The Apex Code documentation states:

> Treat the first argument as a pattern and return a string using the second argument for substitution and formatting in the same manner as apex:outputText and the Java MessageFormat class.

The Java documentation for MessageFormat says:

> Within a String, a pair of single quotes can be used to quote any arbitrary characters except single quotes. For example, pattern string "'{0}'" represents string "{0}", not a FormatElement. A single quote itself must be represented by doubled single quotes '' throughout a String.

Comment: @Robs Yeah, if you're not familiar with Java, and you see a reference to Java in the documentation, you need to *also* check the Java documentation for caveats. As long as you remember this, you'll be okay.